# client connection id passed from nginx to uwsgi

Tags: python, http, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

I am using the following setup:

client -> Nginx -> uWSGI -> Python app

The connection between the client and Nginx is persistent. I am aware that there is no support for persistent connection between Nginx and uWSGI.

Is there a way to pass the Nginx connection ID to uWSGI so I can differentiate between clients? I am trying to differentiate between clients with the following limitation: The client does not support cookies and I cannot modify the client code. The client posts some JSON to the same URL so modifying the URLs does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind:

- Link client to IP address and/or other headers the client is sending;
- Upon first connection create a session ID and change all the links on the page to `/link/to/page?sid=%(sessionid)s`. It's not very pretty but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, those two suggestions won't work for me because 2 clients can have the same IP address and send the same headers. Also, the client uses an API (JSON posted to the same URL) so changing the links on the page does not apply here.